# Rspec Shoulda matcher with private methods

Tags: rspec, shoulda

I'm using shoulda gem and trying to test some private methods:

```
  it { should respond_to (instance_eval{:get_user_status})}
  it { should respond_to (instance_eval{:send_email_notification})}
```

But the tests are failing because both the above methods are private. How can I properly test their responsiveness using shoulda matchers?

Answer (score 1):

write a custom matcher like :respond_to_private example

```rb
RSpec::Matchers.define :respond_to_private do |expected|
  match do |actual|
    actual.respond_to? expected, true
  end
  description do
    prefix = actual.is_a?(Class) ? '.' : '#'
    "respond to #{prefix}#{expected}"
  end
end
```

and then use it in your tests

```rb
it { is_expected.to respond_to_private :method }
```

Answer (score 0):

To test a private method, you have to call that using `send`. You can test it this way:

```
it "tests private methods" do
  my_object = MyObject.new
  expect(my_object.send(:get_user_status)).to eq 'some_value'
  expect(my_object.send(:send_email_notification)).to eq 'some_other_value'
end
```

Answer (score 0):

You *could* use `send` to test private methods... but you really shouldn't be doing that. Tests are used to confirm that your object behaves in a way that you expect, so that when other code, whether it's yours or not, uses your object, you know what's going to happen. Private methods are internal to the class you're creating; they aren't callable from anywhere but your class, so they should already be exercised indirectly by tests for the public methods that use those private methods. You can essentially treat your private method as an extraction of your public code. Sandi Metz gave a *great* talk on unit testing that I recommend watching if you want to learn more about this; the part that talks about private methods is [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=URSWYvyc42M&feature=youtu.be&t=15m47s).